# Godot collision not working when nodes added in specific order

Tags: collision-detection, godot

While trying a minimal 2d tutorial, I created tileset, exported it and used it in a scene with player. If I keep StaticBody and KinematicBody at the top, the collision is not detected between them.

Here is the hierarchy of tileset-scene:

```
Node2D
   StaticBody2D
     CollisionShape2D
     Sprite
```

Here is the hierarchy of game-scene:

```
Node2D-Level1
   Tilemap
   KinematicBody2D
     Sprite
     CollisionShape2D
     Camera2D
```

In tileset, when I change order to this, collison starts working:

```
Node2D
  Sprite
    StaticBody2D
      CollisionShape2D
```

Finally, now when I change it back to original order, collision keeps working.
Is there some property being set during the reordering, which enables collision.

Any clues? Or its a bug?